# How might a broken netcat transfer be completed?

Tags: rsync, netcat

For reasons of speed, I've got `netcat` sending a big, single `.tgz` archive file from one computer to a remote computer. In my observations `netcat` is faster than `rsync` for this sort of transfer. The transfer was set up in a way like the following.

On the receiving machine, the following command was run first:

```
time nc -vl 33333 > archive.tgz
```

On the sending machine, the following command was run second:

```
time nc -N $SERVERIP 33333 < archive.tgz
```

On the receiving machine, the progress can be interpreted by measuring the (known) size of the file that is being received:

```
ls -al --block-size=M
```

Now let's say the transfer were interrupted somehow. Say the sending computer has a power cut or the internet connection died. Under the assumption that restarting the transfer is excluded as an option (due to the time taken to transfer the large file), what would be a reasonable way to pick up the transfer? Could `netcat` somehow pick up the transfer again? Would `rsync` be able to pick up the pieces and complete the transfer?

Comment: rsync should handle that without any trouble. It was designed for that. The speed may change with selecting a different `--block-size` for it's "delta-transfer" algorithm, or by using an rsync daemon on the receiving side instead of ssh. With netcat, you would have to script around it to give it only what needs to be appended, and use `>>` instead of `>` on the receiving side. And be sure to make no error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, rsync will scan the file on each side in chunks, and transfer only the chunks that are missing.

Note that rsync (usually) transfers your data via an encrypted SSH tunnel, whereas netcat is transferring the data in clear text (you may be aware of this, but random readers should beware!)